# GSAP Tween taking longer on each play in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gsap

I am using GSAP's timeline to animate elements and it looks like it's taking longer and longer each time. In the example below, you can click on the box to animate it, and then click to reverse it. You can see in my setup that I don't have any delays set. If you open the console you will see the log takes longer and longer to execute the message in the onComplete function.

From research I've done, it looks like I am somehow adding a Tween, but I can't figure out how to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. [CodePen here.](https://codepen.io/schrdr/pen/RwpPREw?editors=0111)

```js
const { useRef, useEffect, useState } = React

// set up timeline
const animTimeline = gsap.timeline({
  paused: true,
  duration: .5,
  onComplete: function() {
    console.log('complete');
  }
})

const Box = ({ someState, onClick }) => {
  const animRef = useRef();
  
  animTimeline.to(animRef.current, {
    x: 200,
  })
  
  useEffect(() => {
    someState ? animTimeline.play() : animTimeline.reverse(); 
  }, [someState])
  
  return (
    <div 
      className="box"
      onClick={onClick}
      ref={animRef}
    >
      
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(false);
  return(
    <Box 
        someState={someState}
        onClick={() => setSomeState(prevSomeState => !prevSomeState)}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />,
document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

I think the issue here is that you've the `animTimeline.to()` in the component function ***body*** so this adds a new tweening to the animation each time the component is ***rendered***.

[Timeline .to()](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/to())

> Adds a `gsap.to()` tween to the end of the timeline (or elsewhere using
> the `position` parameter)

```
const Box = ({ someState, onClick }) => {
  const animRef = useRef();
  
  animTimeline.to(animRef.current, { // <-- adds a new tween each render
    x: 200,
  })
  
  useEffect(() => {
    someState ? animTimeline.play() : animTimeline.reverse(); 
  }, [someState])
  
  return (
    <div 
      className="box"
      onClick={onClick}
      ref={animRef}
    >
    </div>
  )
}
```

## Solution

Use a mounting effect to add just the single tweening.

```
const animTimeline = gsap.timeline({
  paused: true,
  duration: .5,
  onComplete: function() {
    animTimeline.pause();
    console.log('complete');
  },
  onReverseComplete: function() {
    console.log('reverse complete');
  }
})

const Box = ( { someState, onClick }) => {
  const animRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    animTimeline.to(animRef.current, { // <-- add only one
      x: 200,
    });
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    someState ? animTimeline.play() : animTimeline.reverse(); 
  }, [someState])
  
  return (
    <div 
      className="box"
      onClick={onClick}
      ref={animRef}
    />
  )
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit gsap-tween-taking-longer-on-each-play-in-react]

Comment: Thanks so much for taking some time to look at my question, Drew. This is working for me locally now with your solution.

I am a bit new to hooks and react - do you know why I can't put the 'animTimeline.to()' in the same useEffect hook as the play and reverse methods?

Comment: @schrdr For almost the same reason. Each time the `someState` value updates, this triggers the `useEffect` callback. If you placed the `animTimeline.to()` in the same effect then you would add another tween each time. `useEffect` with an empty dependency array is synonymous to a class-based component's `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, where that logic is run only once when the component mounts. `useEffect` with a dependency will also run on mount, but also anytime a dependency updates, so it also covers the class-based component's `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.